# Change node version using nvm and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nvm

I have a Dockerfile running centos/systemd that also installs nvm and have an entrypoint.sh that runs /usr/sbin/init (as required by docs) it also accept an argument from docker-compose command to control the node version being used - BUT it seems the node version is not persistent/kept for some reason.

**How can I control node version from docker-compose file?**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/systemd

# Install & enable httpd
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install \
    httpd \
    autofs \
    gcc-c++ \
    make \
    git \
    fontconfig \
    bzip2 \
    libpng-devel \
    ruby \
    ruby-devel \
    zip \
    unzip
RUN yum clean all
RUN systemctl enable httpd.service

# Setting up virtual hosts
RUN echo "IncludeOptional apps/*.conf" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

# Install nvm to later use in compose
ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 13.10.0
RUN curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash

# install node and npm
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm install 12.16.1 \
    && nvm install 11.9.0 \
    && nvm install 10.9.0 \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

# add node and npm to path so the commands are available
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source root/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use "$@"
node --version
exec /usr/sbin/init
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  httpd:
    build: '..\Web-Server\Apache'
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    command: 11.9.0
```

docker-compose up (output):

```
httpd_1  | Now using node v11.9.0 (npm v6.5.0)
httpd_1  | v11.9.0
```

docker exec -it  /bin/sh -lc "node --version":

```
v13.10.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: A Docker image typically does _one_ thing.  You don’t really have any reason to install three versions of Node in a Dockerfile, for instance, because the single application that the container runs will only use one of them.  Don’t use a version manager like `nvm`, just directly install the single version of Node you need as the “system” Node inside the image.

Comment: That's a setup for development and I have different projects requiring different versions

Comment: Each project can have its own `Dockerfile` to accommodate this.

Comment: Since I have multiple projects with multiple needs, each runs a few containers, the idea is to create a few containers and then mix and match each project with docker-compose. Creating a different docker file for each node version will make it hard to maintain since this container also runs apache and a fee other services, so each change not related to node will make me modify all docker files. I really hope to get that command to work... Except that everything else I've described works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a dockerfile for each project then, combine them with docker-compose files, for each deployment, that is your best option. If you want to facilitate for code reuse you can look at creating a generic base image to which all your dockerfiles use.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after endless searches across the web.
2 things to note/change:

1. We need to set the default node version as well (inside the shell script). Unfortunately, I don't no why it's necessary to set it as default to keep it persistent but it just works (if anyone can explain that, please do). So entrypoint.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source root/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use "$@" && nvm alias default "$@"
node --version
exec /usr/sbin/init
```

2. when running bash with `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh -c "node --version"` and not in interactive mode or login to shell it will not read startup scripts so node version set by using `source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh` and `nvm use XXX` is not red and thats why it's not "changed" for this specific bash session. Solution is to login to container and run `node --version` from within OR source nvm.sh as well before running node --version e.g. `docker exec -it <container_id> sh -c "source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh && node --version"`

Hope that helps to anyone that came across the same issue.